# Error handling with custom messages?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

How can I throw error messages (i.e `ErrorType`) with custom messages?

For example:

```
catch let error as MyError {
  print(error.customMessage)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this clean version out. The idea is to implement both String and ErrorType protocols and use the error's rawValue.

```
enum UserValidationError: String, ErrorType {
  case NoFirstNameProvided = "Please insert your first name."
  case NoLastNameProvided = "Please insert your last name."
  case NoAgeProvided = "Please insert your age."
  case NoEmailProvided = "Please insert your email."
}
```

Usage:

```
do {
  try User.define(firstName,
                  lastName: lastName,
                  age: age,
                  email: email,
                  gender: gender,
                  location: location,
                  phone: phone)
}
catch let error as User.UserValidationError {
  print(error.rawValue)
  return
}
```